# Mvc Routing - Friendly URL's

Tags: php, url-routing

From reading up on MVC, I want to steer away from using Requests from client-side scripts and focus on a main router.

From research, urls look something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/controller/action/params
```

However, when looking at StackOverflows and other similar frameworks it looks more like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/1365260/example
```

Can someone please explain what is happening in this that's different? 1365260 looks like the users ID & example is his username so these must be the params and users is clearly the controller.

How does this framework know what action to run? Ie: search, view, update

Comment: Pretty URLs, routing/dispatching requests, and faux "MVC" are all orthogonal. You can have either without the others. And the simplistic module→function→args path structure just isn't applied everywhere.

Comment: As a side note, would the directory /id/username need to be created or is .htaccess used? Because you'd get a 404 not found and creating all these directories would use up server memorey so whats best practice? @mario

Comment: Now, Stack Overflow in particular doesn't even use Apache. But yes, a RewriteRule can map any virtual path structure without the directories even existing. Note that a .htaccess ruleset is commonly just used for testing. There are often other options for pretty urls.

Comment: So a pretty url is given, redirected to the router which then handles the given request? Wouldn't the URI state change? @mario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not actually

```
/controller/action/params
```

You can define anything as a route.

```
http://www.example.com/this/is/a/route
```

From laravel framework perspectives- Whenever you visit a URI the framework by default redirects your request to a index page where it checks your URI in the routes list. Where each route is bound to a controllers method which handles your request. This method could do anything like search, view, create, update, delete etc.

In this routing system you can also pass parameters.
Here in your example

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/1365260/example
```

this route is defined in routes list and a method is bound with it and user id, user name these are parameters. Whenever this route is visited it runs the method and it shows the profile of the user id and user name it gets from the route parameter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That first redirect is the confusing part, how can the file redirect but keep the same URI state? Unless the directory /uniqueId/username doesn't exist and is mapped with htaccess.. Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Yes it is mapped with htaccess. Which redirects all request to a single file.

Comment: How does the URI state not change? A ReWrite should surely changed the URI to the path mapped like /id/username -> index +1 and marked answer for explanation though - appreciated!

Comment: It has nothing to do with the path. .htaccess does not change the URI

Comment: If the URI is virtual (the directory doesn't actually exist) id assume a 404 would be thrown and the htaccess would redirect the URI to the 404.php file. But i suppose this is a seperate question